# Wo steht, dass man im Deutschen Wörter im Normalfall kleinschreibt?

Tags: spelling, capitalization

Ich habe soeben das Dokument mit dem Titel »[Regeln und Wörterverzeichnis entsprechend den Empfehlungen des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf)« wegen einer Recherche zur Groß- oder Kleinschreibung durchforstet.

In diesem Dokument sind Fälle geregelt, bei denen es notwendig ist, ein Wort mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben zu schreiben. Es sind auch Fälle geregelt, in denen es Ausnahmen zur Großschreibung gibt, die dann ausdrücklich eine Kleinschreibung erfordern.

Beispiel:

> § 55: Substantive schreibt man groß.
>   § 56: Klein schreibt man Wörter, die formgleich als Substantive vorkommen, aber selbst keine substantivischen Merkmale aufweisen.

§ 55 legt fest, dass in »Ich nehme meinen Teil« der *Teil* großzuschreiben ist; § 56 fordert aber (quasi als Ausnahme vom § 55), dass in »Ich nehme daran teil« »teil« kleinzuschreiben ist.

Alle Regeln, die im verlinkten Dokument eine Kleinschreibung fordern, sind solche Ausnahmen von Großschreiberegeln. Kleinschreibung wird also immer nur nach den Schema »Wenn X zutrifft, ist großzuschreiben, wenn aber Y zutrifft, gilt die Großschreibung nicht, in diesem Fall ist kleinzuschreiben.« definiert.

Aber wo ist z.B. geregelt, dass in dem Satz

> Ich fliege fort.

die Wörter »fliege« und »fort« kleinzuscheiben ist?

Angenommen, ich würde behaupten, stattdessen wäre folgendes richtig:

> Ich Fliege Fort.

Welche der vielen Regeln, die der Rechtschreibrat herausgegeben hat, könnte diese Behauptung widerlegen? Ich kann weder eine explizite Regel finden, die aussagt, dass Wörter kleinzuschreiben sind wenn nicht ausdrücklich eine Regel eine Großschreibung verlangt, noch steht irgendwo, dass die Regeln, welche eine Großschreibung verlangen, vollständig sind. (Die Regeln, die eine Kleinschreibung verlangen, sind, wie ich annehme, ja tatsächlich unvollständig. Warum sollte man dann die Vollständigkeit der Großschreiberegeln annehmen?)

Das [Wörterverzeichnis](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/woerterverzeichnis2006.pdf) hilft bei meinem Beispiel auch nicht weiter, denn es enthält die Einträge

- Fliege
- fliegen
- fort
- Fort

Es erklärt aber nicht, was die Wörter bedeuten. Außerdem erhebt das Wörterverzeichnis nicht den Anspruch vollständig zu sein, so dass ein fehlender Eintrag im Verzeichnis nicht automatisch aussagt, dass es das Wort nicht gibt oder dass es falsch wäre.

Comment: Vorbemerkung (2) sagt, wann Großschreibung zu verwenden sei. Ich denke, man darf davon ausgehen, dass in allen anderen Fällen klein zu schreiben ist - Einen dritten Weg gibt es ja nicht.

Comment: Ich bin ja irgendwie versucht, das Tag [[tag:legal-terminology]] hinzuzufügen.

Comment: Zusatzfrage: Welche Regel sagt aus, dass es nicht "Ichfliegefort" heißt?

Comment: Nixda: DubleibstDa

Comment: Wenn ich abwägen müsste, ob ich das Regelwerk lieber so nehme, wie es ist (zugegeben mit Lücken, die man aber mit ein bißchen "common sense" auffüllen kann), oder einen Juristen einstelle, der es in alle Richtungen "wasserdicht" macht, dann... Es handelt sich hier ja weder um einen Gesetzestext noch um eine mathematische Abhandlung.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Welche der vielen Regeln, die der Rechtschreibrat herausgegeben hat, könnte diese Behauptung widerlegen?

Zwei Ansätze:

1. Die Vorbemerkung des Abschnitts zur Groß- und Kleinschreibung (Kapitel D, Abschnitt 0, Seite 53) beginnt mit:

   > (1) Die Großschreibung, das heißt die Schreibung mit einem großen
   >   Anfangsbuchstaben, dient dem Schreibenden dazu, den Anfang bestimmter Texteinheiten sowie Wörter bestimmter Gruppen zu kennzeichnen und sie dadurch für den Lesenden hervorzuheben.
   >
   > (2) Die Großschreibung wird im Deutschen verwendet zur Kennzeichnung von
   >
   > - Überschriften, Werktiteln und dergleichen
   > - Satzanfängen
   > - Substantiven und Substantivierungen
   > - Eigennamen mit ihren nichtsubstantivischen Bestandteilen bestimmten festen nominalen Wortgruppen mit nichtsubstantivischen Bestandteilen
   > - Anredepronomen und Anreden

   Offensichtlich funktioniert eine Kennzeichnung mit Großbuchstaben nur dann, wenn man sie sonst nicht verwendet.¹
2. In den Regeln zur Laut-Buchstaben-Zuordnung (Kapitel A) werden ausschließlich Kleinbuchstaben erwähnt. Wenn Du die Schreibung Deines Beispiels von Grundauf rekonstruieren möchtest, erhältst Du mit Abschnitt A zunächst:

   > ich fliege fort

   Mit Abschnitt D (und § 67 für den Punkt) wird dann daraus:

   > Ich fliege fort.

---

<sup>¹ streng genommen betrifft das aber nur den Wortanfang und man dürfte hiernach also immer noch schreiben: »ICH fLIEGE fORT.«</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Im verlinkten Dokument unter D, 0 - Vorbemerkungen, (2) ist die Bedeutung der Großschreibung als Mittel zur *Kennzeichnung* festgehalten. Daraus geht meiner Meinung nach klar hervor, dass Kleinbuchstaben der Regelfall sind.

Der Abschnitt enthält eine überschaubare Liste von 6 Punkten. Daran anschließend werden Regeln für Sonder- und Grenzfälle erläutert.

Dass fliege und fort im genannten Satz kleingeschrieben werden geht daraus hervor, dass es nicht in der Liste enthalten ist.
Es handelt sich **nicht** um

- eine Überschrift
- einen Satzanfang
- ein Substantiv oder eine Substantivierung
- Eigennamen
- feste nominale Wortgruppen
- Anredepronomen

In Abschnitt (3) wird auf die Besonderheit hingewiesen, dass neben den Regeln zur Großschreibung auch ergänzende Regeln zur Kleinschreibung angefügt werden müssen.

Die Großschreibung wird nicht als Regelfall mit einer Liste von Sonderfällen präsentiert, sondern als Liste von Anwendungsfällen mit einer ergänzenden Liste von Ausnahme- und Sonderfällen.

Comment: »Klar hervorgehen« geht zwar anders (nämlich in Form einer expliziten Aussage), aber du wirst wohl recht haben.

Comment: Auf die Schnelle konnte ich im gesamten Dokument nichts finden, dass man Wörter als erkennbare Buchstabengruppen zusammenhalten muss und nicht mit beliebigen, variablen Abständen versehen darf.
Also wieso nicht auch noch zufällige Leerzeichen einstreuen?
I______c__h_______f_l______i____eg____e________fo_____rt.

Answer (score 0):

Sicherlich hast Du Abschnitt D in folgendem Dokument gelesen: http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/amtliche_Regelungen.pdf

> In einigen Fallgruppen ist eine eindeutige Zuweisung zur Groß- oder Kleinschreibung fragwürdig. Hier sind beide Schreibungen zulässig.

Das dürfte die Frage beantworten. Obschon es hier zur Großschreibung heißt:

> Die Großschreibung, das heißt die Schreibung mit einem großen Anfangsbuchstaben, dient dem Schreibenden dazu, den Anfang bestimmter Texteinheiten sowie Wörter bestimmter Gruppen zu kennzeichnen und sie dadurch für den Lesenden hervorzuheben.

Wenn also die Großschreibung eine besondere Hervorhebung ist, dann kann man sie aus meiner Sicht als Abgrenzung vom Standard verstehen. Und da es nur zwei Fälle gibt, nämlich Großschreibung oder Kleinschreibung wäre der Standardfall eben die Kleinschreibung.

Zu Deinem Beispiel

> Ich Fliege Fort.

Du kannst ja gerne `Ich Fliege Fort` schreiben. Es wird nur nicht verstanden werden, da es einfach die Aneinanderreihung von einem Personalpronomen und zwei Substantiven ist, nämlich

> Ich
>   Fliege
>   Fort (Knox)

Wenn Du sagen willst, dass Du wegfliegen wirst, musst Du eben schreiben

> Ich fliege fort.

Nur dann hat der Satz die gewünschte Bedeutung, denn nur dann enthält er das *Verb* "fliegen" und das *Adverb* "fort". Dies wird nämlich erst dadurch kenntlich, dass beide aufgrund der Wortarten klein geschrieben werden müssen.

Comment: Nein eben nicht. Man kann eben nicht schließen, dass alles andere klein geschrieben werden muss. Nirgendwo steht, dass die Regeln, die eine Großschreibung verlangen, vollständig sind. Die Regeln, die eine Kleinschreibung verlangen sind ja, wie meine Frage beweist, ja ebenfalls unvollständig.

Comment: In der Mathematik nennt man so etwas eine axiomatische Unvollständigkeit.

Comment: Es gibt aber auch einen Regelsatz, der besagt, wann Wörter klein geschrieben werden. Trifft keine dieser Regeln auf ein Wort zu, dann wird es nicht klein geschrieben, denn würde es klein geschrieben, müsste auch eine der Kleinschreibungsregeln darauf anwendbar sein. Da keine der Kleinschreibungsregeln auf »Fliege« und »Fort« anwendbar ist, sind diese Wörter also groß zu schreiben.

Comment: Du hast recht: Es gibt nur zwei Möglichkeiten: Großschreibung oder Kleinschreibung. Dadurch, dass es einen Regelsatz gibt, der sagt, wann Kleinschreibung gilt, ergibt sich, deiner Argumentation zufolge der Regelsatz für die Großschreibung automatisch. Da der Fall »Ich Fleige Fort« von den Kleinschreibregeln nicht geregelt ist, gilt also Großschreibung.

Answer (score 0):

Nirgends steht die. Weil es auch keine Regel gibt, die einem ausdrücklich folgende verallgemeinerte Groß- und Kleinschreibung verbietet:

> GOtt

und

> gOTT

wobei sonst, aus einer atheistischen Perspektive, letzteres bis auf die typographische Geschmacklosigkeit die beide teilen, gar lustig wäre.

Comment: Eine Frage, die mit »Wo« beginnt, fragt nach einem Ort. Eine Antwort, die mit »Weil« beginnt, liefert eine Begründung. Eine Begründung ist kein Ort. Daher beantwortet dieses Posting die gestellte Frage nicht. Vergleiche: »Wo wohnt Mario? - Weil er Italiener ist.«

Comment: *GOtt* – Witzigerweise wurde das im Fraktursatz teils wirklich gemacht, und zwar speziell mit diesem Wort (und ein paar ähnlichen).